# Rails 5 belongs_to weird behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Client Class

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
 validates_presence_of :name, :email
 validates_email_format_of :email, :message => 'is not looking good'
 validates_uniqueness_of :email

 has_many :projects
end
```

Project Class

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :client, optional: false

   validates_presence_of :name 

end
```

And schema of my tables

```
create_table "clients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "phone"
    t.string "address"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "client_id"
    t.string "description"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Sometime I want to create Project without having client specified. So I added option :option false. And so now I'm able to create project without specifying any client id. However when I try to create project with client_id, it accepts any value for client_id i.e. if enter 8 and if this id is not present in client then also its accepted. I want in such cases it shouldn't save this project.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

I have  rails version 5.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some changes, is optional: true, optional: false is the default behavior and expects to get a associated record every time, with that said, you could do something like this:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :client, optional: true

    # Sorry, small bug, client_id? with value zero would return always false and it becomes zero when you input strings or false
    # validates_presence_of :client, if: client_id?
    validates_presence_of :client, unless: Proc.new{ |d| d.client_id.blank? }
end
```

This would validate the client record when the client_id is present

```
p = Project.new                 # => #<Project id: nil, client_id: nil, ...
p.valid?                        # => true
p.client = Client.first         # => #Client id: 1, ...
p.valid?                        # => true
p.client = nil                  # => nil
p.valid?                        # => true
#Non-existent id 10
p.client_id = 10                # => 10
p.valid?                        # => false
p.errors.full_messages          # => ["Client can't be blank"]
p.client_id = 1                 # => 1
p.client                        # => #Client id: 1, ...
p.valid?                        # => true
```

You can even use a custom message

```
validates_presence_of :client, message: 'invalid client', if: :client_id?
```

Finally, just a recommendation, use t.references on your migrations to be able to use foreign keys and get this fields indexed

```
t.references :client, foreign_key: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write your own custom validation to ensure that the id of the client actually exists in your database before persisting the project record:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :client, optional: false

   validates_presence_of :name

   validate :validate_client_id, if: :client_id?

  private

  def validate_client_id
    errors.add(:client_id, "is invalid") unless Client.exists?(self.client_id)
  end 
end
```

The validation will only run if the field is not blank. Which is convenient since `client_id` is optional in your case.

Comment: I tried, it gave me error -> "Unknown key: :allow_blank. Valid keys are: :on, :if, :unless, :prepend. Perhaps you meant to call `validates` instead of `validate`?" . So I changed it to Validates, but then it gave me error -> "You need to supply at least one validation"

Comment: Oh that's right thanks for pointing that out. I changed my answer. Basically, since it's a custom validator you'd just need to add  a `if: client_id?` so it only validates when there is an actual value meaning `client_id` isn't blank (since you are allowing it to be blank in certain instances)

Comment: yes, it is working now, but sorry, I already accepted previous post as answer as it solved my problem. Anyways, thanks